# Create a new column in a dataframe from values in the rows of the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column with values in the rows of the same dataframe such that the value of cell in Year column matches the header and puts value in the row cell under Value. Please see attached image. Any suggestions?

[image: Input and Output Dataframes]

Answer (score 1):

You may need find the function of `lookup`

```
pd.DataFrame({'Year':df.Year,'Value':df.set_index('Year').lookup(df.Year,df.Year)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all the years in the index are also in your columns, you can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {2008: 5*[1], 2009: 5*[2], 2010: 5*[3], 2011: 5*[4], 2012: 5*[5]},
    index=[2008, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2012]
)

np.diag(df.loc[df.index, df.index])
```

Result:

```
array([1, 4, 3, 2, 5])
```

Comment: I dont know if all the years are there. I need a more generic solution :(